# Jquery form success value using in if else

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I was using the same code before and it was working well now it works but problem is returning value. I test the value which is returning from saving page its "true" but in if else no matter what else condition works.

```
<script>
function save(){
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'save.php',
    data:$('#form').serialize(),
    success: function (result){
        if (result=="true")
        {
            $("#message").html("saved!");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#message").html("oops!");
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Edit: Php save the form to mysql and return true I can get it with alert(result) but if else condition doesn't care about it. Jquery ver. jquery-2.1.1.min.js

```
<?php
$save=mysql_query("Insert into table_pr(textval) Values ('$textval')");
        if($save>0)
        {
            json_encode("true");
        }
        else
        {
            json_encode("false");
        }
?>
```

**Solution:** `dataType: 'json'`, this line is missing and saving page I used json_encode("true"); and it works now thanks for help.

Comment: Just use `console.log(result)` and post, what you get? Also a typo missing `}` at the end

Comment: where is the PHP then?

Comment: Could it be that its actually returning the string value '"true"'?

Comment: Does the PHP do `echo "true"` or `echo true`? The latter will actually print `1`. Take a look in the Response section of the Network tab to see what's actually coming back?

Comment: See the jQuery API Docs [jQuery Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) as the parameters to your callback function are different from what you are declaring. Also try using the 'complete' callback instead as 'success' will only be called if the Ajax call is a success.

Comment: I tried .done instead of success still same.

Comment: can you do a `console.log(result);` inside the `success: function (result)` block and post what it says.

Answer (score 0):

The string contains the " symbol at the start and end, so check if the string is equal to '"true"' instead.

Comment: Why do you think string is _"true"_ and not _true_?

Comment: very much possible, and the OP said "*is returning from saving page its "true"*", which brings me to the fact that the return could possibly be a string of "true" and not a Boolean.

Comment: I mean string can have value _true_ (`var str = 'true'`), not value _"true"_ (`var str = '"true"'`).

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST**

PHP's mysql_query returns either TRUE for success or FALSE on fail
 try true for 0 and false for the else statement

**SECOND**

why do you wanna go with that solution

```
<?php
if(mysql_query("Insert into table_pr(textval) Values ('$textval')"))
{
            echo "true";
}
        else
        {
            echo "false";
        }
?>
```

Thats how it should be. Code neatly!

Comment: Thanks for the quick tip, thats better.